# Getting status 500 when scraping amazon product

Tags: node.js, express, web-scraping, axios

I am trying to scrape amazon products. For this I am using nodejs, expressjs and axios.

This is one of the alternatives I´ve tried:

```
const getProductUrl = (productId) => `https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/${productId}`

function getPrices(productId){
    const productUrl = getProductUrl(productId);
    try {
        const response = axios.get(productUrl);
        console.log(response.data)
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.response.data)
    }
    
}
```

And the other alternative is by a custom endpoint

controllers/products.js

```
const axios = require("axios");

//@route   POST /product-word-cloud
//@desc    Create product word cloud
//@access  Public


exports.createWordCloud = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const productUrl = "https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00VVOCSOU";
        const response = await axios.get(productUrl);
        console.log(response)
        res.json(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
    }
}
```

routes/products.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const {
    createWordCloud
} = require('../controllers/products');

router.get('/create-word-cloud', createWordCloud);
module.exports = router;
```

In both methods I´ve got a status 500 with a internal server error.

I think Amazon is somehow blocking my requests for web scrapping.

Is there any solution or alternative to this?

Comment: Amazon does not allow scraping, pure and simple